# Spring + Hibernate DAO: get method for many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, dao

According to this tutorial:

[hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)

i can't use a @id like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

but i must implement `StockCategoryId.java` and `StockCategory.java`

now i'm implementing DAO class for StockCategory.

How can i write the getStockCategory method?

For others entities, i always used something like this:

```
public StockCategory getStockCategory(int id)  throws RecordNotFoundException
{   
    StockCategory stock_category= (StockCategory) getCurrentSession().get(StockCategory.class, id);

    return stock_category;
}
```

but in these classes that implements my many-to-many relationship i should implement the same method but passing 2 ids:

```
public StockCategory getStockCategory(int stock_id, int category)  throws RecordNotFoundException;
```

**question 1: How can i implement this method ?**

As example, i show you how i implement the delete method:

```
public void deleteStockCategory(int stock_id, int category_id)  throws RecordNotFoundException
{       
    /*
    * get the record
    */
    StockCategory stock_category = getStockCategory(stock_id, category_id);


    /*
    * if exists, delete the record
    */
    if (stock_category != null)
    {       
        getCurrentSession().delete(stock_category );
    }
}
```

**question 2: should i implement also a DAO class for StockCategoryId ? If yes, which methods do i have to put in?**

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**
You're using the JPA annotations here with hibernate. JPA requires the primary key to be wrapped up in a type if you want to get by Id. For most of your entities you're using a standard Java type such as long. In this case though you've got a compound primary key (it's made up of more than one field). This means you have to create a custom type (a class) to wrap up the primary key.

In the example you've already done this with the class StockCategoryId. Note that this class is annotated as embeddable. It's not a distinct entity with it's own table. It's a group of columns that can be embedded in as many different entities as you like. In this case it's being used to collect together the two columns that form the primary key (using the embeddedId annotation). So this is what your DAO should be expecting when you want to get a specific record.

```
public StockCategory getStockCategory(StockCategoryId id) throws RecordNotFoundException
{   
    StockCategory stock_category = 
      (StockCategory)getCurrentSession().get(StockCategory.class, id);

    return stock_category;
}
```

**Question 2:**
There's no point creating a DAO for StockCategoryId as it's not an entity itself. It's just a fragment of an entity. If you asked your DAO to get a StockCategoryId what table would hibernate query?

**Note:**
You may not actually need a DAO to get individual stock categories. It probably makes more sense to retrieve stock categories for an individual Stock or Category. To do this you can use the relevant DAO to get your Stock or Category and then call the method to get the StockCategory collection for that object.

E.G.

```
StockDAO dao = new StockDAO();
Stock stock = dao.findByPrimaryKey(1);
Set<StockCategory> stockCategories = stock.getStockCategories();
```

Or something like that... hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for very detailed and clear answer! you teached me a lot of things

Comment: i'm having a big big trouble making a form with checkboxes for this many to many relationship.. i wrote a question about this.. if someone could take a look i would be very very happy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633603/form-with-checboxes-for-a-many-to-many-relationship-spring-mvc-webflow-thyme

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map composite keys as primary keys then indeed you will need to create the StockCategoryId class, since the two integers together are your primary key.

The id class needs to be annotated with @Embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
class StockCategoryId implements Serializable {
  Integer stockId;
  Integer categoryId;
}
```

while your entity will now have a field of the type StockCategory annotated with @EmbeddedId instead of @Id;

```
@Entity
class StockCategory implements Serializable {
  @EmbeddedId StockCategoryId stockCategoryId;
}
```

Then you will always use the StockCategoryId class when you search for the entity in the persistence context instead of the int you are used to.

Take a look at the hibernate docs for further explanation:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity

However I'm not sure where your many to many relationship is in your data model example, since these are composite keys in one entity, and that one entity isn't linked to anything else.